# does time complexity changes according to language?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Relation between time complexity and programming language. means below piece of code take o(N) in c , is that code take same time complexity in java?

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sequence of statements
}
```

Comment: That depends how the code is translated into the other language. The potential difference is not with the loop, but with "sequence of statements"... If you have a doubt, then focus on a concrete case.

Comment: if sequence of statements is same  in both language's codes , then that should be same??

Comment: is below code take same time complexity and space complexity for both c and java??

int s=0;
int N=5;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 s=s+i;
}

Comment: Yes for that particular example.

Comment: Complexity and time are not exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity is just how long an algorithm will take to run as a function of the size of the input.

So for this specific example (and most cases tbh) yes, it’ll run in the same time complexity regardless of programming language.

The only exception I can think of are built in functions, for which every language may have their own time complexity

Comment: Built in functions are always optimised, so they will have the same time complexity (or extremely close).

Comment: if i use max() in c++ and Math.max() in java,  should we consider max() and Math.max() to calculate time complexity of respective codes or we can skip those built in functions to calculate time complexity of respective codes???

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which time we are talking about: if it is the algorithm, both C and Java executed the data entry at the same time. However, it is worth remembering Java runs in a virtual machine, and C runs directly on the computer. Therefore, C will run the program faster.